# How strong are the Pleiades maids in overlord?

Tags: overlord

Narberal Gamma uses twin dragon lightning which I believe is approximately 7th tier magic. Yuri Alpha uses weather modification magic which is 6+ tier magic. I know they're weaker than the floor guardians, but did the show/Manga/LN go into just how strong they are? I got the impression that each one could have beaten Evileye on their own, but the only reason Entoma didn't was because of vermin bane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I found elsewhere:

> The light novels have the stats, but in order of ranking:
>
> Narbarel Gamma (63) was chosen to accompany Momonga because she was
>   the best combatant of the group and the one that can interact best
>   with humans without being found out.
>
> Lupusregina Beta (59) is just below her and is also allowed to fight
>   autonomously and like Narbarel, also human-like.
>
> Solution Epsilon (57) follows that order as well, being one of the
>   field pleiades though in her case, she's not very good for missions
>   that require excessive contact.
>
> Yuri Alpha (52) is the leader in terms of order, but is significantly
>   weaker than the first half of the Pleiades. However, she is still
>   massively overpowered by NW standards though it still takes her and CZ
>   Delta to keep Evileye on edge. Like the Pleiades weaker than her, she
>   is not a field agent and is generally relegated to the tomb.
>
> Entoma (51) is also comparable, but unlike Yuri, she is freakish up
>   close and is ill-suited for field activity especially since she draws
>   attention to herself.
>
> CZ Delta (46) is the weakest and is actually weaker than some of the
>   strongest new worlders (shown in the latest novel where she needed
>   prep time in order to actually be effective in comparison to the
>   steamroller that is Narbarel). She is generally ill-suited for field
>   activity since her low level makes her a poor choice to work
>   autonomously. However, she is a sniper, so she generally won't be
>   working autonomously on the Nazarick team to begin with.
>
> Aureole Omega (???) is likely the strongest and is generally a
>   function guardian and has yet to appear. However, she is highly likely
>   to be a 100th level NPC due to the insinuation of her role.

Evileye is about level 50 and would have lost to Entoma if she didn't have vermin bane, potions, and assistance.

Answer (score 1):

around Level 50 - 65 for the usual Pleiades Six Stars. They are meant to function as a group, delay the enemy so that Ainz guild can prepared and assembled in the throne room

if I am not mistaken, I read from some source that the reason they are low level is either level restriction where the total levels of Pleiades maids are limited to a certain cap by the guild system something like 400 (Nazarick's total level cap was noted to be 2750), or that the nature of Pleiades being the delaying force for enemies that manage to get past all floor guardians in previous levels means Pleiades most likely will be wipe out. And the lower the level of the maids, the lower the revival cost

here is the power ranking chart compiled by someone else: https://i.redd.it/5vxzqk80b2tz.jpg

Answer (score 1):

In the *Overlord* universe, there are several power indicators, but you should first know that the power ratings about the Great Tomb of Nazarick come from the Yggdrasil game and do not concern the new world where they were transported. Yggdrasil indicator are 2 indicators:

1. The global class level which is delimited by the "example" species: a human will never be able to exceed level 60 and will never be able to separate the magic of rank 6.
2. Ability points which count the different abilities of a player, it is therefore possible that a character has more points than another but with a lower level like Lupusregina with Narberal Gamma.

As for the indicators of the new world, we have the association of the guilds of the adventurers which gives military plates according to the levels and which is very regulated, the iron plate being the weakest and adamantite the highest. Then we have the classes much less regulated which designates more notoriety, as an example, clementine heroic class (adamantite, therefore, assumed equal or stronger than an adventurer of adamantite rank). We also have the 13 heroes reputed all of heroic class as well as Momon more recently.

For the subject of the Pleiades maids, they are classified by power like this:

1. Aureole Omega
2. Narberal Gamma
3. Lupusregina Beta
4. Solution Epsilon
5. Yuri Alpha
6. Entoma Vasilissa Zeta
7. CZ2128 Delta

To finish the differences in levels which come from Yggdrasil or from the new world do not in any way affect the outcome of a fight, the best example being the fight of Ainz against Shalltear or even Climb against Succulent.